# Swift3.0 get data with AFN and json switch to swift dictionary always wrong,help me

Tags: json, crash, afnetworking, swift3

```
 NetworkTools.shareBetworkTools().post(path, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (_, JSON) in

        // this sentence crash info: libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC:
        let account = UserAccount(dict: JSON as! [String : AnyObject?])

        account.saveAccount()

        }) { (_, error) in
           print(error)
    };
```